# You don't have permission to access storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

my project work great locally 
but when i upload it to an shared hosting 
i did some changes like 
move the

1. Create folder : public_html/MyApp
2. Move my project (using filezilla ) to public_html/MyApp
3. at Server moved the public_html/MyApp/public/* to public_html
4. changed the index.php

   ```
   require __DIR__.'/MyApp/vendor/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/MyApp/bootstrap/app.php';
   ```

but i did get this error

when trying to load file

### You don't have permission to access /storage/images/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp_2x.png on this server.

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Check your local permissions on the folder vs the shared hosts folder perms

Comment: okey  first i linked the storage/app/public tt public_html/storgae and i don't know what o do next

Comment: You need to set `storage` directory permissions to `777` recursively.

Comment: @Jamesking56 No, don't do that. That's highly insecure. Better to *properly* set permissions, by giving the webserver access to that folder. `chown` or Linux ACLs are ideal.

Comment: What user would that be for cPanel @ceejayoz ?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access `/storage/`, i.e. in the root of the file system. Shared hosting generally won't let you do anything outside of your account's directory.

Comment: @Jamesking56 Dunno, I avoid cPanel like the plague. Probably `www-data` or `apache` or something similar.

Comment: @Jamesking56 - the cPanel is really just a collection of server actions put into a nice UI. Behind the scenes, if it came down to it, you could implement everything by yourself through shell.

Comment: sorry guys i  didn't get you